# Python: Adding subscribers to mailchimp with bulk API V3

Tags: python, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Im trying to write a function to create subscribers in mailchimp, but I get an error, and I can't understand what is wrong.

Im using [python-mailchimp](https://github.com/charlesthk/python-mailchimp)  (And yes, I have mye correct list-id and not 000000)

My code:

```
from mailchimp3 import MailChimp
def export_to_mailchimp():

    #Get all users in DB
    users = User.objects.all()
    
    
    #Create list for dictionaries
    databody = []


    #loop through queryset
    for userobject in users:
    
        #Create dictionary
        databody_item = {
            "email_address": item.email,
            "status": "subscribed",
            "merge_fields": {
                "FNAME": item.first_name,
                "LNAME": item.last_name
            }
        }
        #Append to list
        databody.append(databody_item)    


    client = MailChimp(settings.MAILCHIMP_USER, settings.MAILCHIMP_KEY)
    batch = client.batches.create(data={"operations" : [{"method":"POST", "path":"/lists/00000/members/", "body":databody}]})
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 188, in __call__
    return self._get_current_object()(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 420, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/DOMAIN/PROJECT/apps/members/tasks.py", line 2340, in update_mailchimp
    batch = client.batches.create(data={"operations" : [{"method":"POST", "path":"/lists/000000/members/", "body":databody}]})
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mailchimp3/entities/batches.py", line 53, in create
    return self._mc_client._post(url=self._build_path(), data=data)
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mailchimp3/mailchimpclient.py", line 25, in wrapper
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/mailchimp3/mailchimpclient.py", line 71, in _post
    r.raise_for_status()
  File "/home/USER/.virtualenvs/DOMAIN/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 862, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://us12.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/batches
```

Anyone see what Im doing wrong?

## Update

If I do `"body":json.dump(databody)` I don't get the same error, but `Schema describes object, array found instead`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct way

```
from mailchimp3 import MailChimp
def export_to_mailchimp():

    #Get all users in DB
    users = User.objects.all()


    #Create list for dictionaries
    operations = []


    #loop through queryset
    for userobject in users:

        #Create dictionary for body
        databody_item = {
            "email_address": item.email,
            "status": "subscribed",
            "merge_fields": {
                "FNAME": item.first_name,
                "LNAME": item.last_name
            }
        }
        #Create dictionary for a operation
        operation_item = {"method":"POST", "path":"/lists/000000/members/", "body":json.dumps(databody_item)}
        #Append to list
        operations.append(operation_item)    


    client = MailChimp(settings.MAILCHIMP_USER, settings.MAILCHIMP_KEY)
    batch = client.batches.create(data={"operations": operations})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working one:

```
client = MailChimp(USERNAME, APIKEY)
def fill_list(list_id, subscribers_data):
    data = {'operations': create_subscriptions_data(list_id, subscribers_data)}
    client.batches.create(data)

def create_subscriptions_data(list_id, users_data):
    return [{'method': 'PUT',
             'path': 'lists/{}/members/{}'.format(list_id, str(md5(user['email_address'].encode('utf-8')))),
             'body': json.dumps(user)} for user in users_data]
```

I guess the problem with method which need to be post. For more detail you can use below link.I found out there :
https://devask.cz/questions/42175544/how-to-unsubscribe-delete-list-members-using-mailchimp3-in-python