# How can I update subscriber tags using mailchimp3 for Python?

Tags: python, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0, mailchimp-api-v3

I am trying to update the tags for members of a MailChimp list using the mailchimp3 package/API on a regular basis using purchase data from an external source. The tags need to be updated weekly based on recent purchases by customers. Sample data is below:

```
original_contacts = pd.DataFrame{'First Name': {0: 'Michael',
  1: 'James',
  2: 'Josephine',
  3: 'Art',
  4: 'Lenna'},
 'Last Name': {0: 'Ox',
  1: 'Butt',
  2: 'Darakjy',
  3: 'Venere',
  4: 'Paprocki'},
 'Email': {0: 'mox@gmail.com',
  1: 'jbutt@gmail.com',
  2: 'josephine_darakjy@darakjy.org',
  3: 'art@venere.org',
  4: 'lpaprocki@hotmail.com'},
 'Account Name': {0: 'Lenixi, Co.',
  1: 'Lenixi, Co.',
  2: 'Lenixi, Co.',
  3: 'Fouray, Co.',
  4: 'Fouray, Co.'},
 'Purchase': {0: 'No Purchase',
  1: 'No Purchase',
  2: 'No Purchase',
  3: 'Purchase',
  4: 'No Purchase'}}
```

I have successfully been able to create new members and update the merge fields of existing members using this script that I modified from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42828112/python-adding-subscribers-to-mailchimp-with-bulk-api-v3):

```
list_id = '123456'
operations = []

for index, row in original_contacts.iterrows():
    databody_item = {'email_address': row['Email'],
                     'status': 'subscribed',
                     'merge_fields': {
                         'FNAME': row['First Name'],
                         'LNAME': row['Last Name'],
                         'COMPANY': row['Account Name'],
                     },
                     'tags': [row['Purchase']]
                    }
    operations.append(databody_item)

def upload_list(list_id, subscribers_data):
    data = {'operations': create_subscriptions_data(list_id, subscribers_data)}
    client.batches.create(data)

def create_subscriptions_data(list_id, users_data):
    return [{'method': 'PUT',
             'path': 'lists/{}/members/{}'.format(list_id, user['email_address']),
             'body': json.dumps(user)} for user in users_data]

upload_list(list_id, operations)
```

The script above will create a tag for a new member, but does not update tags for existing members. I have also tried variations of the code below to see if I can update the tags for a single member, but have had no success:

```
client.lists.members.tags.update(list_id = list_id, subscriber_hash='xxxxxxxxxxx', data = {'tags': [{'name': 'Purchase'}]})
```

This does not throw any errors, but also doesn't do anything to existing tags.

The only solution I have come up with is deleting all existing tags manually and updating every single contact with new tags. However, this is extremely inefficient and I would like to 1) avoid updating tags that haven't changed and 2) want to accomplish everything within my app.

All help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find all tag-related content here: https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/guides/organize-contacts-with-tags/.
Just make sure to change the coding language in the code boxes from the default, "BASH" to "PYTHON"

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update the tags for a user via a patch.  It only works as describes in the documentation when you are adding a new subscriber.

I talked to Mailchimp and suggested they at least make that clearer in the documentation.